# Print data received by REST call when using @Resource in Grails

Tags: rest, grails, groovy, annotations

Following along with groovies docs on REST, i've setup a model like so:

```
import grails.rest.*
@Resource(uri='/books')
class Book {

    String title

    static constraints = {
        title blank:false
    }
}
```

I'd print out the parameters I receive when creating and saving.  Is there away to override these methods created by the `@Resource(uri='/books')` annotation?  Or handle the annotation a closure or something to do this?

Comment: Have you tried the obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have 2 choices if you wish to have a default RESTful interface and modify it somewhat for your needs.

1. Use the `$ grails generate-controller [Domain Class Name]` command that will generate the appropriate controller and change the generated file as needed.
2. Create a Book controller and extend the `RestfulController`; then override the default methods with the `@Override` annotation, print/log the params, and then call the matching `super` method.

   ```
   import grails.rest.RestfulController

   class BookController extends RestfulController {
       static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']
       BookController() {
           super(Book)
       }

       @Override
       def save() {
           println params
           super.save params
       }

       @Override
       def update() {
           println params
           super.update params
       }
   }
   ```